# Configure Map in Spring to return prototype bean

Tags: java, spring

I have configured a map in spring which returns me the instance based on key. But the thing is it always returns me the same instance of the map entries(plate, spoon, fork) instead of creating a new instance every time even though the bean is a prototype. What am i missing?

Please note i am working on a very old version of spring.
Here my configuration:

```
<bean id="plate" class="com.xyz.items" singleton="false"/>
<bean id="spoon" class="com.xyz.items" singleton="false"/>
<bean id="fork" class="com.xyz.items" singleton="false"/>

<bean id="ItemFactory" class="com.xyz.items.ItemFactory" >
        <property name="registeredItems">
            <map>
                <entry key="spoon" value-ref="spoon"/>
                <entry key="plate" value-ref="plate"/>
                <entry key="fork" value-ref="fork"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

//Here's the stuff in java

public class ItemFactory {

    private Map registeredItems;


    private Item getItem(String item ){

        Item item = (Item)registeredItems.get(item);

        return item;        
    }}
```

|

Comment: default bean type is Singleton and hence when you don't type 'scope="prototype"', it will create singleton bean

Comment: @vishal.biyani `singleton="false"` is equivalent to `scope="prototype"` see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: Oops, my bad, I didn't read code thoroughly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that since `ItemFactory` is `singleton` it all it's life holds reference to same instance of Bean no matter that referenced bean is `prototype` scoped. Spring doesn't care about prototype scoped bean destruction, it simply creates new instance of bean when it's referenced from singleton and that's it.

You are referencing bean with smaller scope (`prototype`) from bean with larger scope (`singleton`), that's problematic.
See [referencing prototype beans from singletons](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction)

There are two solution for this case:

1. Use method injection as described in link above.
2. In `getItem()` method retrieve beans directly from Spring application context.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, i guess its pretty clearly written the spring source docs.